# Modem escape sequence (+++) passed as data

Tags: modem

one question regarding modem, Hayes escape sequence.
First to explain what is happening:

```
==> ATD 123\r\n
<== +CR: REL ASYNC\r\n
<== CONNECT 9600\r\n

After this moment I have online session. When I want to hangup, I am doing next.
< no data 1.5 seconds >
==> +++  (no \r\n)
**+++ is received on destination side (why?)**
<== OK
< no data 1.5 seconds >

==> ATH\r\n
<== OK
Destination side gets NO CARRIER.
```

The problem for me is that **escape sequence is received as regular data on destination side**.
Does anyone have an idea what should I do? Some modem configuration tweak?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my question.
I did not find the way to do that.

Instead, in order to hangup I use [DTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Terminal_Ready) (Data Terminal Ready) signal. After switching from active to inactive, the other side determines that as hangup (if modem is configured with AT&D2).